# Which one would be correct to use in a poetic way?

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs

Can I make an interrogative sentence without using any Helping Verb?

For instance:

> Blood is sticking onto the attire on my body; now what my pocket needs for darning?

I want to say my pocket doesn’t need anything for darning because already blood is sticking onto the atire; how should I make “what does my pocket need...” or “what my pocket needs...”?

Comment: Well, first, you might want to say "blood is stuck  _to_". Are you writing a poem? If so, perhaps you could provide a little more context? Poetry involves rhythm, meter, cadence, rhyme (or not), style, and many other devices. What you want to say could be said in many, many different ways. Even if you're writing prose, sentences have cadences and writers use many devices to make them sound "poetic". What you should use would depend a great deal on the structure and style of your text.

Comment: How does blood being on a pocket have any relationship to it not needing darning? That aside, your example sentence is asking with it *does* need for darning, but your explanation is saying that it *doesn't* need anything for darning.

Comment: I’m sorry I don’t have so much knowledge of English how its poetry or verse is created. In this, the excellence has been created that because of madness, the cause of the outflowing of the blood isn’t known to the writer himself, and therefore he can’t express it nor can he tell whether at the time of tearing the pocket, his breast has been scratched by his fingernails, or it was because of someone’s throwing some stone; or he may have heedlessly fallen into thorn bushes, or wept tears of blood. To my knowledge, from their not being mentioned, all these specific causes become more enjoyable.

Comment: "What need my pocket for darning?"  -Perhaps a little old fashioned.

Comment: Poetry often accomplishes its aesthetic effects by creative departures from the standard rules of language use. The departures can, however, accomplish these effects well only if they are very carefully thought out, and based on an understanding of the subtleties of the language that is **far** above the average for native speakers. It is unwise to attempt to write poetry in a particular language if one does not have this, very rare, command of it.